# Cannot label F2FS (SELinux)

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, security, selinux, f2fs

I'm running Arch Linux [testing] x86_64

For some reasons, I can't relabel my root file system (F2FS) with SELinux (custom kernel compiled, using refpolicy)

Kernel ver

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                                                                       ⏎
Linux PenArch 3.16.3.201409282025-1-grsec #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Chcon error:

```
# chcon -t mozilla_exec_t /usr/lib/nightly/nightly
chcon: failed to change context of ‘/usr/lib/nightly/nightly’ to ‘system_u:object_r:mozilla_exec_t’: Operation not supported
```

Here is my config snippet:

```
CONFIG_F2FS_FS=m
CONFIG_F2FS_STAT_FS=y 
CONFIG_F2FS_FS_XATTR=y
CONFIG_F2FS_FS_POSIX_ACL=y
CONFIG_F2FS_FS_SECURITY=y
CONFIG_F2FS_CHECK_FS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX=y 
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_BOOTPARAM_VALUE=0
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DISABLE=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_DEVELOP=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_AVC_STATS=y
CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_CHECKREQPROT_VALUE=1
# CONFIG_SECURITY_SELINUX_POLICYDB_VERSION_MAX is not set 
CONFIG_DEFAULT_SECURITY_SELINUX=y
```

Comment: What method are you using to generate this Kernel config?

Comment: What command are you running, what's the actual error and what's recorded in `/var/log/audit/audit.log` when you run it?

Comment: SELinux support was added to F2FS [only about a year ago](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/6/7/39). Are you sure that feature has made it into the kernel you're using? Have you found reports of others actually using it?

Comment: @tyler-maginnis it's just an snippet of my configuration extracted from the running kernel.

Comment: Invoke this: $> `uname -a` and add it to your Question.

Comment: @Warren Young I'm using kernel 3.16.3 and CONFIG_F2FS_FS_SECURITY description saying that it support SELinux

Comment: I'm on my phone now so I can't provide any log or output right now. If you want any info, just ask and they will be provided when I get to my PC